# Determine the Z-Transform for the following sequence: $ |n|(\frac{1}{2})^{|n|} $

Tags: z-transform, homework

Determine the Z-Transform for the following sequence:

$$ |n|(\frac{1}{2})^{|n|} $$

I have tried to solve the above problem. However, the answer that I got is the negative of what is given in the solution manual. What I may have done wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

SOLUTION FROM SOLUTION MANUAL:

[image]

Comment: What book is this from? Is this the official solution manual?

Comment: @MattL. This is from Oppenheim Signals and Systems. Yes, this is the official solution manual.

Comment: Strange that there seem to be so many mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always good to do a sanity check on such results. E.g., you could try to see that $X(1)$ equals the sum of all time domain samples:

$$X(1)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x[n]\tag{1}$$

With $x[n]=|n|\left(\frac12\right)^{|n|}$ it is clear that the result of $(1)$ must be positive. However, for the solution from the manual you get $X(1)<0$, whereas for your solution you obtain $X(1)>0$. So I think you can be confident that your solution is the correct one.